# cassandra system_auth does not show users, permissions tables , not able to create user

Tags: cassandra

DSE version 5.1

wanted to create a super user, but not able to create.

system_auth keyspace does not know USERS, PERMISSIONS tables.

cassandra@cqlsh> use system_auth;
cassandra@cqlsh:system_auth> desc tables;

resource_role_permissons_index  role_permissions  role_members  roles

cassandra@cqlsh:system_auth>

cassandra@cqlsh> create user admin with password 'pwd' superuser;
Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Only superusers can create a role with superuser status"
cassandra@cqlsh> use system_auth;

Comment: As the Error Message say "Only superusers can create a role with superuser status"

Comment: Are you a superuser? If not, either contact one or ask to become one.